# How to Implement surface Codes for quantum error correction

Tags: surface-code

How would one go about implementing a basic surface code for X and Z error corrections? I have read a bunch of papers, I think I semi-understand its working. But I have absolutely no idea about how to implement it. I have tried implementing it using CNOT gates but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a repetition code as a quantum circuit? It's an easier version of the surface code you can use as an easier problem to get the hang of it.